# Dealing with overloaded functions that have ambiguous parameters

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Take this small example class (not my real code, but it exposes the problem):

```
Convert = class(TObject)
  public
    class function ToString(value: Double): String; overload;
    class function ToString(value: TDateTime): String; overload;
  end;
```

It compiles fine until you try to use the `Double` or `TDateTime` functions As
In:

```
var
  d: Double;
begin
  d := 99.99;
  ShowMessage(Convert.ToString(d));
```

You will get this compile error: Ambiguous overloaded call to 'ToString'.
The problem boils down to the fact that `TDateTime` is a type of `Double`

My Question: how do You deal with this type of problem?

**EDIT - I am NOT looking for a solution for the example given**

I have found 3 Solutions so far:

- Rename one of the 2 functions
- Add a "Dummy" parameter to one of the 2 functions
- Change the parameters to Var types, this has the disadvantage that I can no longer call this function with constants

are there any other solutions out there?

Comment: I rename those DateTime functions

Comment: If it gets ugly I'd rename them all: `DoubleToString`, `DateToString` and skip the `overload`. Using `var` parameters is a bad idea: makes the functions less useful and confusing. Using double-standards (some functions overloaded some functions not) is again confusing.

Comment: I'm using the Dummy parameter at the moment. The real code uses a fluent interface and renaming the function just doesn't feel right. I am hoping there is a better solution out there...

Comment: @CosminPrund: Renaming them all is out of the question (in reality I have 30+ overloads)

Comment: dealing with aliases (TDateTime is an alias) always causes this kind of ambiguous behavior

Comment: @SirRufo: Yeah I know, but should Delphi not respect the fact that it is another Type? (even if it is an alias). I believe .NET doesn't have this problem...

Comment: maybe, but it doesn't - just pass a TDateTime to TValue and you will not know from TValue that it was a TDateTime. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.TypInfo.TTypeKind - In fact you get the same bytecode using Double, Extended or TDateTime. How can this resolved to the alias type? (just spoken Delphi)

Comment: @SirRufo Indeed but in RTTI you would look at the TRttiMember.MemberType's Name and you know what Type you have

Comment: I tested your example in XE,XE2,XE3 and they compile and execute fine.

Comment: @LURD: doesn't matter that's just an example (it is not my real code). I just want some advice from You guys how you would deal with this kind of problem...

Comment: @whosrdaddy, then post real code that exposes your problem.

Comment: @LURD `ShowMessage( Convert.ToString( 99.99 ) );` that causes the `E2251` compiler error

Comment: Add that to your question, but the simple solution here is: `Convert.ToString( Double(99.99))` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @LURD I am asking this question in a broader sense, how would YOU deal with this problem, I am not asking for a solution for the code I posted. David's answer is a good example of what I want...

Comment: Renaming the functions is a good advice, but you already gave that option in your question. Opting for a an explicit type definition in case of constants as in my comment above is another alternative.

Comment: @LURD `Convert.ToString( Double(99.99) )` -> `E2089` compiler error (Invalid Typecast)

Comment: @SirRufo  indeed, my bad.

Comment: @LURD no problem, I had the same in mind but a running IDE at sight to test before post, my luck :o)

Comment: @SirRufo, `Convert.ToString( Double(Variant(99.99)))` works.

Comment: @LURD +1 a real double conversion :o)

Comment: @whosrdaddy I don't think .NET has this problem because .NET probably doesn't use a `double` as its `DateTime` class.

Comment: @JerryDodge it is not about double/datetime, I just gave an example to illustrate the problem - look at the problem in a broader sense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overloaded methods can be very effective. However, as soon as there is a hint of ambiguity they become a liability. A good example of this are the new TStream overloads introduced in XE3. It's not hard to fall into a trap where the compiler chooses an overload that you weren't expecting. At least in your code the compiler stopped. In that sense you were lucky.

So my advice, in your situation, is to abandon overloads. Express the different input types in the method name. Yes it's a little more verbose, but you won't make any mistakes, and you code will compile!

Comment: mmm, so no Hidden Golden Egg? That's a pity :)

Comment: +1, totally agree. I fell once in one of these compiler traps (on Delphi 2006) and I went nuts until I discovered what happened

Comment: Is it possible to use generics here ? `TConvert.ToString<T>(value : T):string`

Comment: @teran That sounds plausible. The implementation would stuff value into a TValue and go from there, I guess.

Comment: Sadly, it seems this is the most sane thing to do ;)

Comment: Or come up with your own little overridden version of a `TDateTime` which is its own record or something. Sounds like more of a headache, but could actually help.

Comment: @JerryDodge You cannot override a `TDateTime`.

Answer (score 5):

Your posted example compiles and executes fine in XE.

In a comment you give this example instead:

```
ShowMessage( Convert.ToString( 99.99 ));  // <- gives compiler error 2251
```

In this particular case the solution is to explicitly define the type( I thought):

```
ShowMessage( Convert.ToString( Double(99.99) )); // <- E2089, Invalid Typecast
```

Looking into the documentation:

> > This error message is issued for type casts not allowed by the rules. The following kinds of casts are allowed:
> >
> > - Ordinal or pointer type to another ordinal or pointer type
> > - A character, string, array of character or pchar to a string
> > - An ordinal, real, string or variant to a variant
> > - A variant to an ordinal, real, string or variant
> > - A variable reference to any type of the same size.

So, to explicitly tell the compiler to select the `Double` overloaded function:

```
ShowMessage( Convert.ToString( Double(Variant(99.99)))); // Ok
```

A bit convoluted perhaps. But for the other overloaded function it is simpler:

```
ShowMessage( Convert.ToString( EncodeDate(2013,1,5));
```

---

> Update

---

To make this a generic solution working for all classes, consider adding class functions to resolve your ambiguous types.

```
Convert = Class(TObject)
  ...
  class function AsDouble( value: Double) : Double; inline; static;
  class function AsTDateTime( value: TDateTime) : TDateTime; inline; static;
end;

class function Convert.AsDouble(value: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := Value;
end;
class function Convert.AsDateTime(value: TDateTime): TDateTime;
begin
  Result := Value;
end;
```

Now you can call your overloaded class function with constants:

```
ShowMessage( Convert.ToString( Convert.AsDouble(99.99)));
```

Comment: My answer is more about how to specify the intended type for an overloaded function call, in those cases the compiler is not able to resolve that without help.

Comment: I see, typecasting could be a solution but I then I prefer renaming the function :) (+1 for your answer)

Comment: It seems a little awkward to convert something from integers, to a string, to a date, back to a string again...

Answer (score 1):

How about collapsing it all?:

```
class function Convert.ToString(value: Variant): String;
begin
   Result := VarToStr(Value);
end;
```

Comment: The point is not about a String Conversion but how you would deal with ambiguous overload parameters. This solution has one big problem, it opens the parameter possibility to more types than intended

Comment: My point isn't about a string either ;-) but about the variant. You're right about the 'more types then intended' but if it's the OP's own code he can just support the intended types and uses an 'else' or an assertion for the rest.

Comment: I was actually going to suggest this and then I saw your answer, Rather than immediately calling `VarToStr()` you can instead check the type of the value and handle it differently accordingly.

Comment: PS - Commenter is the OP, and also, perhaps you should demonstrate the type checking / handling in the code of your answer :)